# cython wrap a C library hangs on fprintf, fprint on Windows 7 MinGW

Tags: cython

I am trying to wrap a C library. It works perfect if I comment all calls to printf and fprintf. But it hangs the python interpreter "python.exe has stopped working" if I uncomment the calls.

Also, the lib needs to catch Crtl+c event to close, however this does seems to not work as well.

The lib uses signal.h to handle ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

I have, by now, solved the problem with:

"#define fprintf(dest,...) PySys_WriteStdout(**VA_ARGS**)"

"#define printf(...) PySys_WriteStdout(**VA_ARGS**)"